# Memory allocation of a list within a list in C

Tags: c, memory, allocation

Is my first time asking a question I'll try to be concise, I am trying to allocate space for a list within a list and access its member afterwards ( int begin int end ).

```
typedef struct patient{
    int id_patient;
    int id_medic;
    char name[15];
    float presale;
    struct seq *sequence;
}patient;

typedef struct seq{
    int begin;
    int end;
    struct seq *next;
}seq;

struct patient* patient_list;
patient_list = malloc(sizeof(patient));
```

However I'm unable to access data in the inside list

```
patient_list->sequence->begin = 10
printf("%d",patient_list->sequence->begin)
```

The code exits with 0xC0000005, which should be due to how to accessing an illegal zone of memory.

Why could this be happening? I wrote only the interested code, since the list on top works.

Answer (score 0):

You've allocated the space for the `patient` struct itself, but the `sequence` pointer within that struct is uninitialized.  You need to allocate memory for that sequence with something like

```
patient_list->sequence = malloc(sizeof(seq) * n);
```

Where `n` is the number of entries in your list.  If the intention of the `next` pointer within the `seq` struct is that it points to the next entry in the list, you'll also need to initialize those pointers in each entry of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can read from or write to the `seq` pointed to by `sequence`, you need to allocate memory for it.

```
patient_list->sequence = malloc(sizeof (seq) );
patient_list->sequence->begin = 10;
printf("%d",patient_list->sequence->begin);
```

If you try to read or write from a pointer that isn't pointing to valid memory, you're going to get undefined behavior, and the exception 0xC0000005 is a typical outcome.

Note that the `seq` still has an uninitialized value in its `next` pointer, which is similarly disastrous if used. So you're going to need to carefully construct your sequence of data, each entry being initialized and pointing to the next.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part in your code is that you allocated memory for the `patient` struct but not for the `seq` struct within the `patient` struct. Essentially, you allocated memory for the `sequence` pointer but no memory for where it is pointing to.

Here is a quick example:

```
typedef struct patient{
    int id_patient;
    int id_medic;
    char name[15];
    float presale;
    struct seq *sequence;
}patient;

typedef struct seq{
    int begin;
    int end;
    struct seq *next;
}seq;

int main()
{
    struct patient* patient_list;
    patient_list = (patient*) malloc(sizeof(patient));
    patient_list->sequence = (seq*) malloc(sizeof(seq)); // we need to allocate the memory here
    patient_list->sequence->next = NULL;

    patient_list->sequence->begin = 10;
    printf("%d",patient_list->sequence->begin);

    return 0;
}
```